# Magento - 'what's this?' popup for persistent basket is not working properly

Tags: magento

In newer versions of Magento there is a persistent basket feature complete with a 'what's this' hint on the login/create account page.

On my 1.6 'blank' based theme this little popup is not doing anything apart from dimming the screen as if it were to show a popup. Firebug shows no errors and, given that there is some Javascript observe in there somewhere with some extra window js that needs loading, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is due to the css required not being present, If you click the "what's this" button you should notice the popup just gets shown at the very footer of the page.

The css is present in the default/default/css/styles.css file or copy the code below to your active theme style sheet.

/* Remember Me Popup ===================================================================== */
.window-overlay { background:url(../images/window_overlay.png) repeat; background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35); position:absolute; top:0; left:0; height:100%; width:100%; z-index:990; }

.remember-me label { float:none; margin:0 6px; }
.remember-me-popup { background:#fff; border:1px solid #ccc; left:50%; top:50%; position:absolute; margin:-85px 0 0 -200px; width:400px; text-align:left; -moz-box-shadow:0 0 6px #ccc; -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 6px #ccc; -box-shadow:0 0 6px #ccc; z-index:1000; }
.remember-me-popup h3 { background:#d9e5ee; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc; font-size:14px; padding:5px 10px; }
.remember-me-popup .remember-me-popup-head { position:relative; }
.remember-me-popup .remember-me-popup-head .remember-me-popup-close { background:url(../images/btn_window_close.gif) no-repeat; display:block; position:absolute; top:7px; right:7px; height:15px; width:15px; text-indent:-9999em; }
.remember-me-popup .remember-me-popup-body { padding:10px; }
.remember-me-popup .remember-me-popup-body a { display:inline-block; height:19px; border:1px solid #de5400; background:#f18200; padding:0 8px; font:bold 12px/19px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-align:center; text-decoration:none; white-space:nowrap; color:#fff; }
/* Remember Me Popup ===================================================================== */